# One to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

To start off, we have the following scenario (not exactly like this but for confidential reason I will not take the risk to explicitly describe the project) where let's say A person can Have Many home addresses and obviously an address belong to at most one person. This is pretty much a one to many relationship where there are 2 tables (Person and Addresses) with the second one holding a FK referencing the owner. But sadly i was told that my system should also allow users to enter  Addresses first, so a FK that does not exist in the Person table yet. I came to the conclusion that i just have to drop that constraint. Do you thing it's a common thing to do? Furthermore I thought to maintain consistency even without FK (declared explicitly), if someone update the Person ID, since i dont want the user to do it in both table, is it possible to create a Trigger (I'm using Mysql server) that will update the second table automatically (if that person has an address)? If yes, any hint to how to  write that (I'm not familiar with triggers)

Comment: Seems simple... you had a constraint -- then were given a requirement that breaks that constraint.  Welcome to a world where you no long have that constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the 1:N relationship by creating the kind of intermediate table normally associated with M:N relationships but adding a uniqueness constraint on the address referencing field; alternatively, you can just make address' reference to person nullable, making it an optional reference.

---

[Edit]

Scripts from MySQL dump wrap their contents with something like:

```
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
....
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
```

As you can probably guess, it temporarily turns off foreign key checks to allow inserting interdependent data out of order. However, you should be sure of the trustworthiness of the import data as I believe it does not recheck the data when turned back on (so it can allow data that violates FK constraints to persist).

If you need the ability to add "address" before "person" with user entered data, then you are back the original situation of needing optional keys or another table; or just not actually saving the "address" info (but instead holding it locally in the data entry program) until after the "person" info is sufficient/complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I understand (and it's a great idea) that we can have a join table (with Unique address). But assume we have a new address to that (all we have new is the ID of the person associated with that address), we first insert in Address Table then when we go on to Insert The PersonID and Address ID in the join table we'll get an error right? Because The PersonID doesn't exist yet in the Person table. Or perhaps i misunderstood something?

Comment: You just defer inserting to the "join" table until you have a person.

Comment: Ok, but how bad is it if i keep it in a 1:N relationship (without FK)? because it's a lot of data I will be importing in the data base, and this solution seems a little complicated to maintain

Comment: How are your primary keys determined? Your initial question implies user entry, not an import process.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, yes my app will ALSO allow import of data and the data will come with their unique Identifier (which i can use as PK if i want). So in my case I can be given a spread sheet of addresses with ID of their owner. Please tell me the best way to go, I'm working on this project with others but They don't know much about DB and i don't want to use something that might cause major problems  later on

Comment: If you're getting data (and primary key values) from elsewhere, I guess your only real solution then is to drop the constraint and rely on the import data being trustworthy. Or, depending on your import process, see incoming edit to answer...

Comment: I guess I'll go with this solution then

Comment: Can I update my question with a possible solution and you tell me if it's feasible?